# Inverse metric tensor: can I use this formula for every case?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors

Suppose you have an Differentiable manifold $\mathcal{M}$ (with $\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{M})=4$) and a metric tensor $g$. Of course then that the components of $g$ are $g_{ab}$. Now, the contravariant metric tensor $g^{ab}$ is a key piece to perform standard calculations, such as Christoffel symbols, and therefore we must to calculate its components.

Now, given a matrix $g_{ab}$, the cofactor matrix is given by:

$$\mathrm{Cof}(g_{ab}) = A^{ab} = (-1)^{a+b}M^{ab} $$

where the $M^{ab}$ is the matrix of complementary minors of $g_{ab}$ $[1]$.

The determinant of $g_{ab}$ is given by:

$$\mathrm{det}(g_{ab}) = g_{0b}A^{0b} =  g_{00}A^{00} + g_{01}A^{01} + g_{02}A^{02} + g_{03}A^{03} $$

I wish to ask:

> **Is the following formula valid for every $g_{ab}$?**
>
> \begin{equation}
>     g^{ab} = \frac{\mathrm{Cof}(g_{ab})}{\mathrm{det}(g_{ab})} = \frac{A^{ab}}{g_{0b}A^{0b}} =\frac{(-1)^{a+b}M^{ab}}{g_{00}A^{00} + g_{01}A^{01} + g_{02}A^{02} + g_{03}A^{03}}
> \end{equation}

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Aren't you missing a transpose in your cofactor formula for the inverse?

Comment: Up to the transpose that Ted pointed out, yes: $(g_{ab})$ is a non-singular matrix, as good as any other, just with function coefficients. So this formula with the adjugate matrix is still up. In the end, this boils down to linear algebra, not actual geometry.